# SSIS: Stop SSIS package execution if any files missing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, dtexec

I have a SSIS package which look for 8 files in a pre-defined location. Using script task I am checking if any files are missing? If any files are missing then I send an email stating files are missing. Now I want to stop the current package if any files are missing after sending email task.

From the Microsoft link:

- [RunningPackage.Stop Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.runningpackage.stop.aspx)

I can see I can stop the ssis package by stopping the ssis service (from the SQL Server which is running SSIS Service) what I do not want to do as I am not sure if it will start the ssis service automatically again. Also I do not have permission to see and run the packages in the ssis server and test this way.

I am not sure about how to stop using DTEXEC tool either. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You could for example count the files and save that into a variable. Then use a worklfow constraint with an expression, and only proceed if there are eight files: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2006/11/01/conditional-constraints/

Comment: Thank you @Nick.McDermaid I have followed the tutorial in the link and it has worked.

Comment: If you want to document your solution in an answer you should be able to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I tried, it is not accepting answer from me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just fail the container by adding code "dts.TaskResult=ScriptResults.Failure".

After that, you can add an "Failure" container (just add a container and change the green arrow to a red one" to send out the email.
Once you do this, you must force a "fail" on the email container and go to the container's properties (you can just right-click and choose "Properties").  Look for "FailPackageOnFailure" and change that to "True".  Hope this helps.